# How to retrieve blank records using talend integration

Tags: integration, talend

I want to retrieve blank records from excel file.
 **Records are:**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | a    |
+----+------+
| 2  | b    |
+----+------+
| 3  |      |
+----+------+
| 4  | d    |
+----+------+
|    | e    |
+----+------+
|  6 | f    |
+----+------+
```

Here I want to retrieve 3rd and 5th record.
Can anyone please give me an idea.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your blank records dont contain space `" "` .Try to use tFilterRow and this conditions :

```
input_row.id == null || input_row.name == null
```

In case that columns are nullable. Otherwise:

```
input_row.id.equals("") || input_row.name.equals("")
```

Comment: Hey thanks 1st one is working. But showing NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this

[image]

using **t filter row**  tried to find blank records.